# How do I redefine a bash function in terms of old definition?

Tags: bash, function

Is there any way I can redefine a bash function in terms of its old definition? For example I would like to add the following block of code to the preamble of the function `command_not_found_handle ()`,

```
# Check if $1 is instead a bash variable and print value if it is
local VAL=$(eval echo \"\$$1\")
if [ -n "$VAL" ] && [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "$1=$VAL"
    return $?
fi
```

It is currently defined in /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh and sourced by bash start-up scripts.

That way I can query the value of an environment variable at the command prompt by simply typing the variable name (and provided that no such command by that name exists). e.g.

```
user@hostname ~:$ LANG
LANG=en_AU.utf8
```

I know I could just copy and paste the current definition and add my own changes in `~/.bashrc`, but I am looking for a more elegant way that involves code reuse.

Better ways of achieving my goal or code improvements/extensions are also appreciated.

Comment: If this question would be better suited on stackoverflow, can someone migrate it over, I don't know how.

Comment: I think [this post on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203583/how-do-i-rename-a-bash-function) answers your question.

Comment: Instead of `eval`, you can use indirection: `local VAL=$(echo ${!1})`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can print out the current definition of the function, and then include it in a function definition inside an `eval` clause.

```
current_definition=$(declare -f command_not_found_handle)
current_definition=${current_definition#*\{}
current_definition=${current_definition%\}}
prefix_to_add=$(cat <<'EOF'
  # insert code here (no special quoting required)
EOF
)
suffix_to_add=$(cat <<'EOF'
  # insert code here (no special quoting required)
EOF
)
eval "command_not_found_handle () {
  $prefix_to_add
  $current_definition
  $suffix_to_add
}"
```

Another approach, which I find clearer, is to define the original function under a new name, and call that from your definition. This only works if you don't need to act on the local variables of the original definition.

```
eval "original_$(declare -f command_not_found_handle)"
command_not_found_handle () {
  …
  original_command_not_found_handle
  …
}
```

Comment: Cheers, it never occured to me to use here-documents, no special quoting required. I think I prefer your first method, makes it easier to view the whole definition with `declare -f`, but I like the way you rename the original func.

Comment: If this isn't evidence that we should stop using bash, then I don't know what is. Thank you Gilles!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @mat, @dennis-williamson . After reading your comments, this is what I got

```
eval 'command_not_found_handle () {

    local VAL=$(echo "${!1}")
    if [ -n "$VAL" ] && [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "$1=$VAL"
            return $?
    fi

    '$(declare -f command_not_found_handle |
    tail -n +3 | head -n -1)'
}'
```

Though I think I prefer @Gilles solution.