# "Inheritance" in bash; Is there a way to call super in overriding function (without eval)?

Tags: bash

Given the file `m.sh`:

```bsh
f() {
  echo foo
}

g() {
  f | sed -r 's/^|$/:/g' # random work
}
```

and `e.sh`:

```bsh
. m.sh

old_f="$(type f | sed '3,$!d')"

f() {
  echo "$(eval "$old_f")bar"
}

g
```

is there a better solution than that use of `type` and `eval` for calling the old function from the overriding function while keeping the same name so references in other functions still work?

Both `m.sh` and `e.sh` are part of the same project, and so we can modify `m.sh` without worry.

Comment: maybe like this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29742/30851

Comment: @frostschutz That also involves `eval` and `type` (in the form of `declare -f`). I can see how my title question is a duplicate of that, but the body question isn't. I've added `(without eval)` to the title.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's any other generic way. It's either eval or copy-paste the function and modify how you like (bad luck if the original shell script is updated and you're still using the old one).

Comment: @frostschutz Yeah, I wasn't really considering files not under my exclusive control. These are all in the same repository. That's another difference with that question that I left implied. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: Well, it's odd to monkey patch your own files... :-)

Comment: @frostschutz That's not really monkey patching, is it? I'm only familiar with the use of the term in Ruby, and it seems like too much of a stretch to use it here. In this case, I have a project repo where `e.sh` represents scripts in `$repo/bin/`, while `m.sh` is a library file called `$repo/lib/common.sh` that the scripts use.

Comment: @frostschutz The way I was looking at this, a file is analogous to a class, the files I source from it are the classes/modules it inherits, and the methods can be overridden. This is like any method override in an OOP language. For the particular functions I'm overriding, I have a `usage()` function that's defined in terms of `usage_summary_pieces()` among other things. Scripts can augment `usage_summary_pieces()` without duplicating code from neither the old version nor `usage()`.

Comment: Somehow, this feels like one of those situations where one really should be using a "real" programming language, not shell...

Comment: @ilkkachu For this little hurdle? Nah. The benefits still outweigh the problems. These scripts necessitate a lot of gluing other commands, piping stuff between them. It just comes out too naturally (concise and readable) in shell language to consider something else. Also, I think it's important realize as much potential in one's tools as possible. Having a pattern to express "inheritance" in the shell, makes it much more usable. (Not that I intend to go crazy with this. I rather avoid the use of the pattern when I can.)

Comment: maybe you'd get more interesting answers if you asked about how to print usage in a modular fashion or something like that (your end goal rather than some intermediate step that might not be the best approach here)

Comment: @frostschutz Well, `usage()` is just an example. I could have done this without the need for overriding functions, for example, by using a variable and making modifications on that. What I was really wondering is if there was a neat way (mostly avoiding `eval`) in which one could override functions in a manner similar to how one would do it in an OOP language. It seems like a more versatile pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just occurred to me that I could do:

```bsh
f_1() {
  echo foo
}

f() { f_1 "$@"; }

g() {
  f | sed -r 's/^|$/:/g' # random work
}
```

```
. m.sh

f_2() {
  echo "$(f_1)bar"
}

f() { f_2 "$@"; }

g
```

It's too bad that this requires modifying `m.sh` to add such boilerplate, but at least it avoids the use of `type` and `eval`.

Having to manually redefine `f()` to increase the number can be avoided by defining it once with the first definition as:

```bsh
f() {
  "$(last_version_of_function "${FUNCNAME[0]}")" "$@"
}
```

by using these definitions:

```bsh
reverse_identifier_words() {
  awk -F_ '
    BEGIN {
      OFS="_"
    }
    {
      for (i = 1; i <= NF / 2; i++) {
        t = $i
        $i = $(NF - i + 1)
        $(NF - i + 1) = t
      }
      print
    }
  '
}

last_version_of_function() {
  declare -F \
  | grep -Eo "\b${1}_[0-9]+\$" \
  | reverse_identifier_words \
  | sort -rn -t_ -k1 \
  | head -n1 \
  | reverse_identifier_words
}
```

This way, `e.sh` can override by simply doing:

```bsh
. m.sh

f_2() {
  echo "$(f_1)bar"
}

g
```

Comment: You could also have a global variable holding the name of the "current version" of the function. Then the jump function would look like `f() { "$FUNC_f" "$@"; }`. Though still, every place that defines a "new" function `f` would need to set `FUNC_f`. But that's probably still better than running a five-part pipeline on _each invocaton_ of the function.

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, the point of the 5-part pipeline was precisely to avoid redefining something with each new override. Redefining a global variable is equivalent to redefining `f()` as I was doing at the start of the answer. There's either option, depending on what one cares about. For example, in the case where `f()` is meant to be called only once ever in any execution of the script, it really hardly matters. Also when using a shell language, one is normally not worried on the overhead of the execution of new processes (as long as they're not pointless). They're your building blocks after all.